# Getting error : The method parseInt(String, int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (String, Duration)

Tags: java, selenium

seek for your advise,

Getting the error :
The method parseInt(String, int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (String, Duration)

Code: Using Selenium 4
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Integer.parseInt(Config.getProperty("implicit.wait"),Duration.ofSeconds(seconds)));

Comment: This error has nothing to do with Selenium and is more related to Java basics

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Duration.ofSeconds(seconds)` returns not a `int` but a `Duration`.

Your error is stating that the function `parseInt(String, int)` requires an `int` as a second parameter, and that you are trying to give a `Duration` to it.

However, what you are actually trying to do is setup a implicit wait for your Selenium Driver. To do that, you need to use the function :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(long time, TimeUnit unit)
```

In your case, that would be :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implictlyWait(Config.getProperty("implicit.wait"), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

As I am not sure what your `Config` class contains, I'm not sure that the code will compile, but you should understand your mistake and be able to correct it by yourself if you understood correctly.

Don't be afraid to ask questions if needed; however, you should know that you should be able to solve this kind of error which are only related to the basics of Java coding. If you still don't understand, I advise you read a few tutorial about the use of parameters in functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response ! I will check on parameters in functions.

Comment: @Sakhi My pleasure ! If the answer helped you and solved your problem, you may accept it to close the ficket